# Get list of PHP openssl_encrypt methods / modes

Tags: php, encryption, php-openssl

I am starting to use PHP's `openssl_encrypt` method. The second argument is the encryption mode. Where can I find a list of all possible methods / modes?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-cipher-methods.php if I understood correctly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While [the manual is scarce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php), it looks like you can use [`openssl_get_cipher_methods()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-cipher-methods.php) to return an array of available cipher methods:

```
print_r(openssl_get_cipher_methods());
```

The `true` argument would return aliases for them, which might be more recognisable, e.g. `blowfish`, `des3` etc. See the manual for an example.

***Edit 2019:*** the manual is no longer scarce.

Comment: Scarce? It even mentions and links that function.

Comment: @AmigoJack I suspect someone has updated that page in the last 4 years... =)